# Dropdown list width modified after removing options

Tags: javascript, html

I removed all the elements of a dropdown list using a for loop and the `remove()` method, and then I added a single element the dropdown, the problem is that the width of the dropdown list has changed.

Basically my code looks like the following:

```
var option = document.createElement("option");

option.text = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].text;

for(i = dropdown.options.length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--)
{
  dropdown.remove(i);
}

dropdown.add(option);
```

Comment: Set fixed width for the select tag using css.

Comment: Have you tried giving a fixed with to the dropdown in CSS?

Comment: share your HTML as well\